# Are there symbolic methods/computing for stochastic processes and stochastic differential equations?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation, stochastic-pde

Are there symbolic methods/computing for stochastic processes and stochastic differential equations? Are there some research trends along these lines? Can this be perspective and fruitful endeavour for research?

I managed to find only SYMPLER - symblic particle simulator. But maybe there are more efforts?